# Domain Configuration in VPS with Cpanel Webuzo

Tags: nginx, vps

I want to ask, I have a VPS and domain previously existing one in it. The vps installed webuzo, using CentOS 6.9 x64, and nginx. My domain managed by cloud flare.

After that I add another domain in it and my file was entered in the vps. Previously the domain of its host to be somewhere else. Just as the primary domain in this vps, new domains I manage to use his cloudflare well. At his point I cloudflare value pointing to the same IP as the primary domain vps continue in registrar NS has also been my domain pointing to NS cloudflare. In previous hosting, the domain is already I remove. obstacles until now the new domain could not be accessed, when accessed redirected to http: // domain .com / cgi-sys / defaultwebpage.cgi

Please help me to solve that problem, where is the harm or there may be other settings. Because this is the first time I manage vps and using webuzo.

Thanks!

Comment: someone please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Add the nameservers of the Primary domain (which you got from the registrar) in the Webuzo Admin Panel. Upon save, it will restart the DNS service on your server.